# Segment faults on program

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to solve a problem in hackerrank called Variable Sized Arrays.

```
input
2 2
3 1 5 4
5 1 2 8 9 3
0 1
1 3

output
5
9
```

The way the problem works is you first get two inputs let's base on the above example, '2 2' here means that we need 2 rows of data and 2 queries. the next input is how many data is in this row '3' means 3 inputs, then the next inputs will be the data in the row so now we should have

```
[ [1, 5, 4], [1, 2, 8, 9, 3] ]
```

now remember in the first line of input the 2nd input is for the number of queries. 
so the next inputs will mean the index of the data we want to print out,
so '0 1' would be the 2nd value in the 1st row. Which is `5` and '1 3' is '9'

Now understanding all that this is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    // get from the user the number of rows and queues he'll be making 
    int row, noQ;
    cin >> row >> noQ;

    int col;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> nums;
    nums.reserve(row);
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        cin >> col;
        nums[i].reserve(col);
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            int data;
            cin >> data;
            nums[i].push_back(data);
        }
    }
    // stores the value in the given index
    std::vector<int> query;
    for (int i = 0; i < noQ; i++)
    {
        int y, x;
        cin >> y >> x;
        query.push_back(nums[y][x]);
    }
    // print out the data from given index
    for (auto x : query)
        cout << x << "\n";
}
```

I'm quite new with vectors so I'm not really sure what's wrong I seem to be getting my seg fault after I have inputted the all the data in my code.

Comment: Hey your code works fine on my system... Can you tell me which version you are using or did you edit the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> std::vector<std::vector<int>> nums;
> ```

You've used default constructor of vector. This vector is empty and doesn't contain any elements.

> ```
> nums[i].reserve(col);
> ```

Here, you access the `i`th element of the empty vector. Because the vector is empty, this index is outside the bounds of the vector. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

Solution: Don't access elements that don't exist in the array. In this case, you could for example use the vector constructor that creates a number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Just an easier way to write the code, always include **bits/std** as it contains all the stl elements.. and **use namespace std**, so that you don't have to always do an std::

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // get from the user the number of rows and queues he'll be making 
    int row, noQ;
    cin >> row >> noQ;

    int col;
    vector<vector<int>> nums;
    nums.reserve(row);
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        cin >> col;
        nums[i].reserve(col);
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            int data;
            cin >> data;
            nums[i].push_back(data);
        }
    }
    // stores the value in the given index
    vector<int> query;
    for (int i = 0; i < noQ; i++)
    {
        int y, x;
        cin >> y >> x;
        cout<<nums[y][x]<<"\n";
    }

}
```